# python html table data parsing

Tags: python, html

I am looking for sample code to retrieve clean output from below mentioned html table code..

```
<td width="40%" valign="top" colSpan="1" style="padding-left:5px;padding-top:4px"><input type="text" id="subscriberDeletionForm_OSILA_DisplayName" name="OSILA_DisplayName" class="roTextField" style="width:300px;" value="Rashmi HK" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"/>
</td>
<td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="firstLabelInRowCell"><label id="subscriberDeletionForm_OSILA_CountryCode_label" for="subscriberDeletionForm_OSILA_CountryCode" class="rwLabel">Country Code:</label>
</td>
<td width="40%" valign="top" colSpan="1" style="padding-left:5px;padding-top:4px"><input type="text" id="subscriberDeletionForm_OSILA_CountryCode" name="OSILA_CountryCode" class="roTextField" style="width:300px;" value="91" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"/>
</td>
<td class="labelCell"><label id="subscriberDeletionForm_OSILA_AreaCode_label" for="subscriberDeletionForm_OSILA_AreaCode" class="rwLabel">Area Code:</label>
</td>
<td width="40%" valign="top" colSpan="1" style="padding-left:5px;padding-top:4px"><input type="text" id="subscriberDeletionForm_OSILA_AreaCode" name="OSILA_AreaCode" class="roTextField" style="width:300px;" value="80" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"/>
```

## **output i need .**

```
OSILA_DisplayName  = Rashmi HK
OSILA_CountryCode  = 91                                                                               OSILA_AreaCode     = 80
```

I am using the following code and able to retrieve it. But i need to extract lot of field in the same way hence i am looking for different way to extract

```
    OSILA_DisplayName = 'id="subscriberDeletionForm_OSILA_DisplayName"'
    f22 = open('delsubinfo1', 'r')
    for line2 in f22:
        if OSILA_DisplayName in line2:
#            print line2
            line2 = line2.split('"')
#            print line2
            OSILA_DisplayName1 = line2[19].strip()
            print  OSILA_DisplayName1

    OSILA_CountryCode = 'name="OSILA_CountryCode"'
    f23 = open('delsubinfo1', 'r')
    for line3 in f23:
        if OSILA_CountryCode in line3:
#            print line3
            line3 = line3.split('"')
#            print line3
            OSILA_CountryCode1 = line3[19].strip()
            print OSILA_CountryCode1
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Did u try anything ?

Comment: Updated with code

Comment: BeautifulSoup is probably the code library you should use to correctly scrape data from HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse html texts.

You can retrieve data from html code like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = open('delsubinfo1', 'r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "html.parser")
for input_tag in soup.find_all("input"):
    if input_tag.get("name") in ('OSILA_DisplayName', 'OSILA_CountryCode'):
        print input_tag.get("name").ljust(18), '=', input_tag.get("value")
# OSILA_DisplayName  = Rashmi HK
# OSILA_CountryCode  = 91
```

Comment: uehara, can we pass name and value as variable for further processing

Comment: Yes, you can. You can get the further information [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).